# Exchanging a brand new laptop because of a dead pixel, is there any way to re-validate my Microsoft Office product key?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, system-restore, system-recovery, product-key

I just bought a brand new laptop (Toshiba Satellite L655-S5155) and realized AFTER I had installed Norton 360 and Microsoft Office Home and Student 2010 that the monitor has a dead pixel.

I'm exchanging the laptop, since I haven't done anything else with it but would like to know if there's any chance that a system recovery or system restore would enable me to use the same product key for these programs on the new laptop?

I know the Norton 360 can be used on up to 3 devices, so I should be able to use it again but the Office Suite is not so flexible.  The only reason I'm apprehensive about having the store simply give me a new suite is because the FIRST issue I had was with them giving me the wrong computer so they have already given me a new Office Suite once before.  I'd hate to ask for another one for free if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing preventing you to re-install Office 2010 as often as you like: While Microsoft does have "excessive activation" limits, they only trigger way down the line, so you shouldn't be worried. Also, Office Home and Student can be installed on three machines simultaneously.